# For loop to write multiple Panda dataframes into a single .xlsx file

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, xlsx

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

in_folder = Path("input folder directory")
out_folder = Path("utput folder directory")

for in_file in in_folder.glob("*.npy"):
    out_file = out_folder / in_file.name.replace("_x.npy", "_data.xlsx")
    data = np.load(str(in_file))
    percentage_coverage = ((np.count_nonzero(data == 3) / (np.count_nonzero(data == 3) + np.count_nonzero(data == 2) + np.count_nonzero(data == 4))) * 100)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Percentage of Coverage': [percentage_coverage],
                       'Plaque Pixel Number': [np.count_nonzero(data == 3)],
                       'Brain Pixel Number': [np.count_nonzero(data == 2)],
                       'Not Brain Pixel Number': [np.count_nonzero(data == 1)],
                       'Fold Pixel Number': [np.count_nonzero(data == 4)]})
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(str(out_file), engine = 'xlsxwriter')         
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet1', index = False)
    writer.close()
```

This outputs a different .xlsx for each .npy folder in the input folder.

What I would like to do is have the data from each .npy folder as a row in the same .xlsx folder. So a single .xlsx file will be outputted with the data of all .npy files in the input folder.

Any idea how I can update my code to do that?

Best,
Diego.

I tried adding a counter at the start of the for loop and concatenate its value to 'data' then write a 'df' for each 'data' and write all 'df's in a single file but that did not work.

Comment: Hello Diego, Welcome to stack overflow! While I look at your question: try to formulate the title as a question (because it helps people with the same problem find it easily).

Comment: I think you should split your code into smaller pieces so that you can focus on what troubles you. I believe you want to [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)(<- see the documentation) multiple files into one, am I right?